# Can someone explain what this theorem is saying?

Tags: general-topology

The theorem in the textbook I'm reading states:

> If $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_p)$ is any element in $\mathbb{R^p}$, then $|x_i|\le\|x\|\le\ \sqrt{p}\sup\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\ldots,|x_p|\}$.

Can anyone explain what this theorem is saying?

Comment: This is not a theorem but a simple geometric observation, using the theorem of Pythagoras. When you understand what the displayed statement is saying then it will be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2D, this says that the diagonal of a rectangle is no longer than $\sqrt{2}$ times the longest side. The "extreme" case where you get equality is a square, and so no larger constant will do. In other words, the constant $\sqrt{2}$ is *optimal* for the inequality in 2D, and that's why it is there.

In 3D this says that the diagonal of a rectangular box is no longer than $\sqrt{3}$ times the longest side. The "extreme" case where you get equality is a cube, and so no larger constant will do. In other words, the constant $\sqrt{3}$ is *optimal* for the inequality in 3D, that that's why it is there.

And so on up the dimensions...

Answer (score 2):

A very direct interpretation: Let $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_p)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Then, $|x_i|$ is lesser than or equal to $\|x\|$, which in turn is lesser than or equal to $\sqrt{p}$ times the supremum of the set $\{|x_1|,|x_2|,...|x_p|\}$.

Comment: Okay, why is the $\sqrt{p}$ there?

Comment: @OscarFlores It will be explained in the proof given in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

In two dimensions, it is the following picture.  If $v$ is the vector $(x,y)$ with $y \geq x$, then $x,y \leq ||v|| \leq y \sqrt{2}$.  But it's not really necessary to have a specific geometric picture in mind here.  The point is only that if you have an upper bound for all of the components of a vector then you can get an upper bound the magnitude of the vector, and if you have a lower bound for any particular component you have a lower bound for the magnitude of the vector.
[image]